# Oracle service Refuses to Start

Tags: database, oracle, listener, tns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiCD2.png)

When i try to start my oracle service the following error occurs.

Please how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to the windows register  i found the solution [here](http://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000071019-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion-when-attempting-to-start-stop-or-pause):

1. Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and    select new DWORD Value
4. Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout
5. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
6. Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
7. Restart the computer